# Set the volume to a specific value on Mac at a specific time using a terminal command

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to schedule a volume increase on Mac, but can't quite get it to work. What I have right now is this command that I execute in the terminal:

```
echo 'osascript -e "set volume output volume 10"' | at 17:03
```

It has no effect, but the interesting thing is that I can use it without the "at" part, but in this case, of course I can't schedule it. Also using "sudo" doesn't help.

My system is "MacOS Big Sur 11.7. 4"

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I’ve never used `at` but I’ve used cron a lot for similar things. Give that a try. Or launchd, but I think cron is simpler, which is all you need here.

Comment: amixer -D default set Master 100%

Comment: @Petepf The question is for macOS, which doesn't use ALSA.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run it at a specific time, a crontab works nicely.

Two ways to set it up in crontab.

1. If you know vi, type

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```

   insert a line or lines

   ```
   0 21 * * * /usr/bin/osascript -e  set volume output volume 0" > /dev/null 2>&1

   0 8 * * * /usr/bin/osascript -e  set volume output volume 100" > /dev/null 2>&1
   ```

   Save it and you're done.  Turn the volume off at 9pm and turn it on at 8am.
2. Alternative method:

   If you already have a crontab type

   ```
   crontab -l > crontab.txt
   ```

   edit crontab.txt and add what you want

   Then run `crontab crontab.txt` to install it.

   If you don't already have a crontab, the first execution of `crontab crontab.txt`

   Installs it.

   Lastly, the "fields" in order

   ```
   minute        0-59
   hour          0-23
   day of month  1-31
   month         1-12 
   day of week   0-6
   command and args
   0 is Sunday.
   ```

`man -a` crontab for more

Comment: Thank you for a nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

I concur with the LaunchAgent idea. It's a quirky tech, but once you learn it, it's robust and flexible.

You don't have to actually make a script, though. LaunchAgents can have multiple arguments.

This lowers volume on mine. It mutes the Mac when it's first loaded (  ) and then at 9:30PM--half an hour before 'quiet time' in my apartment complex.

Put it in your `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/` folder, named `com.example.scheduled.mute.plist` and if you want to rename it, you MUST change both the  key *and* the filename. Label must be filename, minus the .plist extension. It's picky that way...

Also this will only execute if you're logged in (or whoever's home folder it's in) because `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents` is where you put LaunchAgents that run when you're logged in. `/Library/LaunchAgents` would be system wide, but I've never tried to run an AppleScript as root.

Also, the first time you run it, you might get prompted to "allow Terminal to access" or something similar and have to go into System Preferences and allow it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.scheduled.mute</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>set volume output volume 0</string>
    </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>19</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
  </dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this sort of thing on macOS, you should use launchd (check out [launchd plists](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)).

`echo` is a built-in command, so I'm not sure you'll be able to treat that as a daemon. What you may need to do is write a simple script, `set_volume.sh`, which contains:

```
echo 'osascript -e "set volume output volume 10"'
```

Then make `set_volume.sh` executable and treat it as if it were a launch daemon.

Comment: thanks for your help!